# EXCEL - Convert TON to KG incorrect

Tags: excel-formula

I have Excel 365 on MAC.

I want to convert "weight unit" in another "weight unit".
=CONVERT(number;  from_unit;  to_unit)

Why is 1 ton = 907kg ? This should be 1000kg

```css
Amount  Unit        Amount          Unit
1   ton =>  907,18474   kg
1   kg  =>  1000            g
1   g   =>  1000            mg
```

What is the correct way to convert?

Thanks,
Aykut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Britannica encyclopedia defined ton:
ton, a unit of weight in the avoirdupois system equal to **2,000 pounds (907.18 kg) in the United States** (the short ton) and **2,240 pounds (1,016.05 kg) in Britain** (the long ton). The metric ton used in **most other countries is 1,000 kg**, equivalent to 2,204.6 pounds avoirdupois.

Microsoft Excel just support "ton" and "uk_ton"

Answer (score 0):

Excel function did not work for unit conversion from tons (metric) to other weight units.

Excel out of the box function:

=**Convert**(value; from_unit; to_unit)

I would like to share my (workaround) solution with the same attributes as Excel:

=**myConvert**(value; from_unit; to_unit)

```html
Public Function myConvert(value As Variant, f_unit As String, to_unit As String) As Variant
    Dim conversion As String
    Dim position As Integer
    
    Dim unit_array As Variant
    
    unit_array = Array( _
    "mg_mg", "mg_g", "mg_kg", "mg_t", _
    "g_mg", "g_g", "g_kg", "g_t", _
    "kg_mg", "kg_g", "kg_kg", "kg_t", _
    "t_mg", "t_g", "t_kg", "t_t" _
    )
    
    Dim formula_array As Variant
    
    formula_array = Array( _
    "", "/ 1000", "/ 1000000", "/ 1000000000", _
    "* 1000", "", "/ 1000", "/ 1000000", _
    "* 1000000", "* 1000", "", " / 1000", _
    "* 1000000000", "* 1000000", "* 1000", "" _
     )
    
    conversion = f_unit & "_" & to_unit
    position = array_pos(unit_array, conversion)
 
    value = Replace(value, ",", ".")
    
    If (IsNumeric(value) = False) Then
        myConvert = "not a number"
        Exit Function
    ElseIf (position < 0) Then
        myConvert = "unknown unit"
        Exit Function
    End If
  
    myConvert = Evaluate(value & " " & formula_array(position))
    
End Function


Function array_pos(my_array, my_value)
    array_pos = -1
    
    For ii = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)
        If my_array(ii) = my_value Then 'value found
            array_pos = ii
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
End Function
```

Here is the test result:

```css
1   t   =   1           t
                
1   t   =   1000            kg
1   t   =   1000000         g
1   t   =   1000000000  mg
                
1   kg  =   0,001           t
1   g   =   0,000001    t
1   mg  =   0,000000001 t
                
1   t   =   unknown unit    x      because x as unit is unknown
y   t   =   not a number    kg     because y is not a number
```